# How to create a link text in a table using c#

Tags: c#, html

I want to create a table format with two columns where each row will have a ProductTitle and its corresponding URL.

I am using the following code which gives the info in table format. I displays entire anchor tag in second column.

But i want only the Text to be displayed as link in second column. On click of which it should open the URL page.

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();

dt.Columns.Add("ProductTitle");
dt.Columns.Add("Link");

DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
dr["ProductTitle"] = "GOOGLE";
dr["Link"] = "<" + "a href=\"" + "http://www.google.com" + "\">Google" + "</a>";
dt.Rows.Add(dr);

Gridview1.DataSource = dt;
Gridview1.DataBind();
```

Could anyone suggest.

Comment: What is your result of the code? What does not work?

Comment: @derape I think Op is saying the column gets rendered as `<a href='' ... />` instead of actually showing the hyperlink.

Comment: Maybe I didn't understand the question, but if you only want the url text, why are you creating an anchor tag? should'nt it be better just to put the url text without the html format? Or if you are writting directly in webforms you can do this: <% Response.Write(variableThatHasURLText); %> /* NO HTML anchor around it */ in Razor in MVC you would do this: <text>@variableThatHasURLText<text>

Comment: It displays the whole link. I just need the Link Text which on click should redirect. <a href=\"" + "http://www.google.com" + "\">Google" + "</a>

Comment: may be he needs all the properties related to <a> tag like hand cursor etc..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could modify the `.aspx` file as follows:

```
    ...
    <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false">
        <Columns>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="ProductTitle" HeaderText="Product Title" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Link" HtmlEncode="false" HeaderText="Link" />
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
    ...
```

So, you should disable the automatic column generation by setting `AutoGenerateColumns="false"` and format the `Columns` section of the `GridView`. Please note the key element here for the link rendering, which is the `HtmlEncode="false"` attribute. You can also set everything in the code behind file:

```
    GridView1.AutoGenerateColumns = false;

    var productTitleField=new BoundField();
    productTitleField.DataField="ProductTitle";
    productTitleField.HeaderText="Product Title";

    var linkField=new BoundField();
    linkField.DataField="Link";
    linkField.HeaderText="Link";
    linkField.HtmlEncode=false;

    GridView1.Columns.Add(productTitleField);
    GridView1.Columns.Add(linkField);
```

Comment: keep in mind that this is a possible security hole if you populate the field based on user input.  Someone could enter a link text of `"/><script>(malicious script goes here)</script>`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
dr["Link"] = "<a href='http://www.google.com'>Google</a>";
```

I tried

```
Label1.Text = "<a href='http://www.google.com'>Google</a>";
```

It works.

**Second try :**

We cannot save any thing else other than .NET types like string,int .etc ,so try asp:HyperLink like this

```
<ItemTemplate>
 <asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink1" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("ProductTitle")%>' NavigateUrl='<%# Eval("Link") %>'></asp:HyperLink>
</ItemTemplate>
```

and

```
dr["ProductTitle"] = "Goole";
dr["Link"] = "http://www.google.com";
```

Comment: Thanks i too verified. It worked for label. But still showing the whole anchor tag in case of dr["Link"] = "<a href='http://www.google.com'>Google</a>";

Comment: I need to create the records dynamically. So i cannot have hyperlink in the design initially.

Comment: @user1658567 This has the hyperlink in an `ItemTemplate`, which is one type of field you can use (Use an `<asp:TemplateField>`) instead of a `BoundField`.  That will still allow it to be dynamic.

Answer (score 0):

There is actually a specific column designed just for what you want to do, it's the `HyperLinkField` column.

```
<asp:HyperLinkField 
            HeaderText="Header"
            DataTextField="LinkText"
            DataNavigateUrlFields="LinkURL" 
            DataNavigateUrlFormatString="http://google.com/q={0}" />
```

You can then ensure that your data source has the appropriate columns for the link text and navigate url fields.

You can configure it if you have a fixed text or fixed url to use the `Text` or `NavigateURL` properties instead of the Data... counterparts, and you can use or not use format strings as needed.